# Any way to speed up algorithm with 2 nested loops?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans

I’ve got an unfortunate O(n^3) situation, and I could use some advice. In English, the situation is: Print each category name, then for each category, grab every book associated with that category. Then, for each book, grab every author and description associated with that book.

```
<c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
    <h2>${category.name}</h2>
        <c:forEach items="${category.books}" var="book">
            <h3>${book.title}</h3>
                <c:forEach items="${book.authors}" var="author">
                    <h4>${author.name}</h4>
                </c:forEach>
                <c:forEach items="${book.descriptions}" var="description">
                    <p>${description.description}</p>
                </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

It seems like to get all the books by category, and then all the authors and descriptions by book that this is the only way to do this... but that can't be right. I'm new to algorithms and speeded things up, so I'll take any advice you'll offer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see that this is a problem.  What measurements have you performed to prove that this is a problem?  Don't worry about the Big-Oh notation.  If the data sets are small enough, it'll be fine.

Comment: Google brings back millions of hits from a query, but they display one page at a time.  Your users won't want to deal with hundreds or thousands of books in a UI.  You should think about paging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @duffymo, there are simply cases, when you cannot reduce the complexity of algorithm (when printing out output to screen especially). You need to print out all information, there is not much room for optimalization in terms of algorithm complexity.

If you would have to print out something repeatedly, like one particular book for 1 thousand times, then you can do optimalization - you could simply for example "precalculate" authors into one string via concatenation and use that string. That would lead to instead of iterate over all e.g. authors each time the book information is requested, just to take prepared string and print it out. So, for 1000 requests you will do just one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, there would probably be much less categories than books, and also much less descriptions and authors so the largest data structure would be the books. It would not really be much of an O(n^3) situation because there are multiple, smaller structures to be considered, so I don't think it would need much optimization as of now.

Comment: Right, there are fewer categories than books, but each book can have multiple authors (like a textbook) and multiple descriptions (bullet points), so right now the largest data structure is authors. Ex. category: biography could have 10 books, and 5 of those books could have 2 authors each.